# If i have no aspx file, how do i deploy my website onto company server?

Tags: asp.net, razor

Currently, i have a project that uses MVC 5 and it uses Razor cshtml files instead of aspx files. I have deployed webpages using aspx files. However, when i drag and drop my files into the server it does not render and shows me errors.

The after publish files do not have aspx files, is it possible for me to open my views inside chrome without deploying the files into IIS?

Comment: MVC5 do not have aspx file but there are cshtml files .... .cshtml file are also copies under `Views` folder when build is created for MVC application....  Also MVC5 application URLs do not have `.aspx` extensions... they are URLs translating to controller and action methods which returns the View populated with data..

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am using a drag and drop server. I know simply by adding the .aspx in the url of the testing server it will show the web application, but how do i view the web application without the aspx file? Could you enlighten me please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Somehow, the drag and drop server that i used was rendered the whole application on it's own. And the url link was just the name of the folder. My file is called MVC. So, the URL was simply, https://YourDomainName/MVC, and it would render the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have a hybrid app. An Asp.net mvc application do not have webforms by default but you can add webforms with aspx extensions into your MVC project. You just have to publish your project then upload the published application to the server. I hope this would work for your. You have to deploy your compiled application to the server in order to load the view in chrome or you can run directly from visual studio to view in the chrome.

Comment: I am using a drag and drop server. I know simply by adding the .aspx in the url of the testing server it will show the web application, but how do i view the web application without the aspx file? For example, I published my website in a folder called test. But there is no aspx file. What do i put in the URL to view the website?